# How can I store the state of the pseudo-random generator in Perl?

Tags: perl, srand, random-seed

Is there a way to store the current state of the built in pseudo-random number generator in Perl so that when my program is run again, it can pick up the sequence from where it left off rather than starting with a new sequence?

Right now, I am storing where I am as well as the initial seed and then throwing away the initial segment which I have already seen using something similar to:

```
sub consume_upto_n {
    my ($seed, $n) = @_;
    $n = 1 unless defined $n and $n >= 1;
    srand $seed;
    rand for 1 .. $n - 1;
    return;
}
```

For example:

```
srand 0x18;
my @v = map { rand } 1 .. 5;
```

Later:

```
consume_upto_n(0x18, 3);
my @z = map { rand } 3 .. 5;
```

Then, `$z[0] == $v[2]`, `$z[1] == $v[3]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [perl 5.13.4](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5134delta#srand%28%29_now_returns_the_seed), [`srand` returns the seed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5134delta#srand%28%29_now_returns_the_seed):

> `srand()` now returns the seed
>
> This allows programs that need to have repeatable results to not have to come up with their own seed generating mechanism. Instead, they can use `srand()` and somehow stash the return for future use. Typical is a test program which has too many combinations to test comprehensively in the time available to it each run. It can test a random subset each time, and should there be a failure, log the seed used for that run so that it can later be used to reproduce the exact results.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the built-in `rand` allows you to do that.  But you can use a substitute `rand`.  For example, [Math::Random::MT::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Random::MT::Auto) allows you to [serialize its objects](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Random::MT::Auto#Serialization) (presumably including `$MRMA::PRNG`, which is the object that gets used by its replacement `rand`).

I'm not quite sure what the point is, though.  If it's a reasonably random sequence, how can you tell whether you're continuing that sequence or starting a new one?

Comment: @cjm This is for simulation purposes. Say I have a simulation that requires 10,000 draws. The quality of the random number generator does not matter much but the ability to replicate (for any given `perl` + OS + app version combination) a given sequence is important. I want to be able to interrupt it in the middle and pick up from where we left off. This way, I can replicate the exact sequence of events later on by just storing the initial seed.

Comment: Sinan: There's multiple things you're asking for: Being able to continue the sequence at some arbitrary point and being able to restart the exact same point. Both can be done using one of the Math::Random::* modules but from a cursory inspection of the perl sources, this cannot be (easily) done with the builtin rand() even from XS! (Perl may call c library's rand() as part of its rand() and the implementation seems platform dependent.)

Comment: @cjm and @tsee It is better not to have to rely on the built in `rand` anyway.